# Python Tensorflow ML text classification. Model outputs value outside of range

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, text-classification

So I have run into a little problem with a text classifier i put together in python. Heres a breakdown of my code

```
labelsarray = np.array(labels)
```

All of said labels being a number in the range of 0-15 and each corresponding to a sentence pattern

```
tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words = vocab_size, oov_token=oov_tok)
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(patterns)
```

And heres the word index of the tokenizer

```
{'<OOV>': 1, 'that': 2, 'you': 3, 'good': 4, 'i': 5, 'not': 6, 'to': 7, 'do': 8, 'are': 9, 'is': 10, 'it': 11, 'me': 12, 'right': 13, "'s": 14, 'how': 15, 'yes': 16, 'a': 17, 'hey': 18, 'ok': 19, 'im': 20, 'intent': 21, 'hi': 22, 'want': 23, 'new': 24, 'hello': 25, 'thank': 26, 'sir': 27, 'correct': 28, 'what': 29, 'pls': 30, 'please': 31, 'am': 32, 'plz': 33, "n't": 34, 'with': 35, 'yep': 36, 'day': 37, 'doing': 38, 'going': 39, 'fine': 40, 'this': 41, 'add': 42, 'greeting': 43, 'morning': 44, 'have': 45, 'sound': 46, 'agreed': 47, 'no': 48, 'around': 49, 'thanks': 50, 'talk': 51, 'need': 52, 'up': 53, 'leaving': 54, 'now': 55, 'really': 56, 'afternoon': 57, 'thing': 58, 'out': 59, 'adios': 60, 'chau': 61, 'dont': 62, 'incorrect': 63, 'night': 64, 'sup': 65, 'go': 66, 'farewell': 67, 'bye': 68, 'later': 69, 'understood': 70, 'mean': 71, 'nope': 72, 'wrong': 73, 'something': 74, 'there': 75, 'whats': 76, 'adieu': 77, 'soon': 78, 'ttyl': 79, 'affirmative': 80, 'meant': 81, 'for': 82, 'on': 83, 'feel': 84, 'great': 85, 'my': 86, 'an': 87, 'reminder': 88, 'yourself': 89, 'heading': 90, 'gtg': 91, 'chao': 92, 'goodbye': 93, 'didnt': 94, 'tell': 95, 'about': 96, 'some': 97, 'the': 98, 'feeling': 99, 'all': 100, 'bad': 101, 'another': 102, 'be': 103, 'scan': 104, 'send': 105, 'email': 106, 'got': 107, 'wa': 108, 'search': 109, 'get': 110, 'today': 111, 'start': 112, 'of': 113, 'anything': 114, 'command': 115, 'asalam': 116, 'aleykum': 117, 'question': 118, 'mind': 119, 'man': 120, 'we': 121, 'when': 122, 'sick': 123, 'too': 124, 'well': 125, 'low': 126, 'favour': 127, 'and': 128, 'put': 129, 'in': 130, 'remind': 131, 'list': 132, 'havent': 133, 'done': 134, 'yet': 135, 'ive': 136, 'retrain': 137, 'update': 138, 'target': 139, 'whatsup': 140, 'warahmatullahi': 141, 'wabarakatu': 142, 'masalam': 143, 'nam': 144, 'lem': 145, 'ask': 146, 'look': 147, 'try': 148, 'information': 149, 'helping': 150, 'research': 151, 'bring': 152, 'data': 153, 'can': 154, 'understand': 155, 'where': 156, 'happy': 157, "'m": 158, 'had': 159, 'wonderful': 160, 'amazed': 161, 'cool': 162, 'loving': 163, 'starting': 164, 'like': 165, 'never': 166, 'better': 167, 'lucky': 168, 'here': 169, 'sad': 170, 'very': 171, 'disappointed': 172, 'horrible': 173, 'ill': 174, 'its': 175, 'dissapointing': 176, 'irritating': 177, 'irritated': 178, 'suck': 179, 'worst': 180, 'ever': 181, 'everything': 182, 'your': 183, 'gon': 184, 'na': 185, 'intention': 186, 'will': 187, 'addition': 188, 'make': 189, 'note': 190, 'remember': 191, 'were': 192, 'gotten': 193, 'left': 194, 'finish': 195, 'train': 196, 'again': 197, 'added': 198, 'so': 199, 'ta': 200, 'recon': 201, 'reconaissance': 202, 'run': 203, 'program': 204, 'running': 205, 'someone': 206, 'saying': 207, 'supposed': 208, 'schedule': 209, 'current': 210, 'activity': 211, 'should': 212, 'working': 213}
```

```
train_sequences = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(patterns)
train_padded = pad_sequences(train_sequences, maxlen=max_length, padding=padding_type, truncating=trunc_type)
```

The above code would vectorize each sentence so it can be passed into the models input.

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    # Add an Embedding layer expecting input vocab of size 5000, and output embedding dimension of size 64 we set at the top
    tf.keras.layers.Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_dim),
    tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(embedding_dim)),

    tf.keras.layers.Dense(embedding_dim, activation='relu'),
    # Add a Dense layer with  units and softmax activation.
    # When we have multiple outputs, softmax convert outputs layers into a probability distribution.
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(16, activation='softmax')
])
model.summary()

_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
embedding (Embedding)        (None, None, 64)          320000    
_________________________________________________________________
bidirectional (Bidirectional (None, 128)               66048     
_________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                (None, 64)                8256      
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 16)                1040      
=================================================================
Total params: 395,344
Trainable params: 395,344
Non-trainable params: 0
```

So thats the model itself

```
model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
num_epochs = 22
history = model.fit(train_padded, labelsarray, epochs=num_epochs, verbose=1)
model.save(domain_home+'/models/intent/lstm_intentclassifier')
print("Saved model to disk")
```

It compiles and at the end of training usually has an accuracy of 94% on my training data. However when i use the model like so

```
lemmatize_words = ' '.join([lemmer.lemmatize(word) for word in nltk.word_tokenize(text)])
text_as_sequence = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences([lemmatize_words], maxlen=max_length, padding=padding_type, truncating=trunc_type)
padded = tf.keras.preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences(text_as_sequence)[0]
predictions = model.predict(padded)
prediction = np.argmax(predictions)
print(prediction)
```

It more often than not will return a value outside of my defined range of 0-15 like 39 or 55 and that doesnt map to any specific class. Why does this happen and how can I fix it? Heres the full code

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import os
import spacy
import json
import pickle
import nltk

from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer

lemmer = WordNetLemmatizer()
STOPWORDS = set(stopwords.words('english'))
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_md')
vocab_size = 5000
embedding_dim = 64
max_length = 70
trunc_type = 'post'
padding_type = 'post'
oov_tok = '<OOV>'
training_portion = 1


patterns = []
labels = []
domain_home = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))))
modhome = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)))
intentsfile = open(domain_home+'/data/nlu_datasets/intent.md').read().split('## intent:')[1:]
num=0
for intent in intentsfile:
    intentpatterns = intent.split('\n')[1:]
    intentpatterns = [x.rstrip() for x in intentpatterns]
    responseindex = None
    for x in intentpatterns:
        if '- ' in x:
            labels.append(num)
            pattern = x.split('- ')[1]
            pattern = ' '.join([lemmer.lemmatize(word) for word in nltk.word_tokenize(pattern)])
            patterns.append(pattern)
        elif '#### responses' in x:
            num += 1
            break
labelsset = list(sorted(set(labels)))
print(f'So these are the labels as numbers sorted:\n{labelsset}')

print(f'Number of patterns {len(patterns)}')

labelsarray = np.array(labels)

print(f'labels data: {labelsarray}')

tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words = vocab_size, oov_token=oov_tok)
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(patterns)
word_index = tokenizer.word_index
print(word_index)
with open(domain_home + '/models/intent/tokenizer.pickle', 'wb') as handle:
    pickle.dump(tokenizer, handle, protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)

train_sequences = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(patterns)
train_padded = pad_sequences(train_sequences, maxlen=max_length, padding=padding_type, truncating=trunc_type)

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    # Add an Embedding layer expecting input vocab of size 5000, and output embedding dimension of size 64 we set at the top
    tf.keras.layers.Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_dim),
    tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(embedding_dim)),
#    tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(32)),
    # use ReLU in place of tanh function since they are very good alternatives of each other.
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(embedding_dim, activation='relu'),
    # Add a Dense layer with 6 units and softmax activation.
    # When we have multiple outputs, softmax convert outputs layers into a probability distribution.
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(len(labelsset), activation='softmax')
])
model.summary()

model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
num_epochs = 22
history = model.fit(train_padded, labelsarray, epochs=num_epochs, verbose=1)
model.save(domain_home+'/models/intent/lstm_intentclassifier')
print("Saved model to disk")
```

Comment: What does tokenizer.word_index contain? Could you somehow post more / make it morereproducible? Without full code it will be difficult to pin it down.

Comment: Plese read the description of the [tag:ml] tag.

Comment: Please include the output of model.summary() in your question

Comment: Ok ive added the model summary and the full code hope it helps @Dr.Snoopy.